# Unable to write files during run time on Heroku platform

Tags: node.js, file, express, heroku

I am trying to write images using a library in node, the process is actually like it will create a 'images' folder then it will write all images inside it.
But I found it is unable to create any folder.
It is perfectly working on local HDD.
Is there anything I need to do, something like write access?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is able to write images locally, but it is not working on the Heroku platform due to the [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) got by the container that holds your application. This causes unexpected behavior and doesn't support persistent storage.

[Heroku addons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons) can help you facing this situation.